# Flickering cursor

Tags: cursor

Fairly often after doing some editing I will notice the cursor flickering.  It blinks a little with an interval between blinks of around a couple of seconds -- but the intervals seem semi-random.  It does not appear to be an intentional blink.  It happens many times per day but I don't yet know much about what packages or other context it depends on.

Moving the cursor often (not always) seems to cure the problem temporarily, then it reappears again a little later.

Do others have this problem?  Does anybody know anything about the cause?

I will try to narrow down this question over time.  Here's what I know:

- With flymake-cursor-20130822.1032, if I move point to somewhere with an error, the problem reliably appears.  However, disabling flymake does not cure the problem.

Comment: If you have `helm` installed, could you check whether `M-x helm-timers` shows an abundancy of timers with small intervals?

Comment: Yes it does: it lists 100 'Absolute Time Timers' and 6 'Idle Time Timers'.  I suspect the list is truncated at 100 since it looks like there are two absolute timers per buffer. I have 560 open buffers (not counting ido virtual buffers I think), so that may well have something to do with it!